# Scaffold body content is not appearing up - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-pageview

I'm using an advanced page turn widget to show the flipping the effect between pages and it's working perfectly fine on an emulator but when I run the application on the real device, the body content is not appearing up at all (just showing a grey screen)

the page turn widget is wrapped inside the body, so I guess it has to do something with the widget

Note:- The body content is appearing up on an emulator

Package link https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_page_turn

Here is my code

```
class Lyrics extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LyricsState createState() => _LyricsState();
}

class _LyricsState extends State<Lyrics> {
  final _controller = GlobalKey<AdvancedPageTurnState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App Title', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'oswald'),),
        centerTitle: true,
        flexibleSpace: Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/bg.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: SafeArea(child: AdvancedPageTurn( // The body content is not appearing up at all but working fine on emulator 
        key: _controller,
        initialIndex: 0,
        children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/bg.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Title 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, height: 1.8, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'oswald'), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/bg.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                  Text('Title 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, height: 1.8, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'oswald'), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),  
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```